# session does not change?

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

i have problems with the following code that i would like to insert at the top of every page. the main goal is to change language settings. the problem is that when i will post the form, it wont change the session as it should do.

```
<?php

session_start();

$basename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php"); 
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$index_path = $host.'/'.$basename;


if (isset($index_path)){
    //header ('Location:http://www.domain.com/'.$pref_language.'/'.$basename);
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['pref_lang'])){ //looks if this session already exists

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){//looks if the browser has set a default language
        $max   = 0.0;
        $languages = explode(",", (strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])));
        foreach($languages as $language){
            $language = explode(';', $language);
            $q    = (isset($language[1])) ? ((float) $language[1]) : 1.0;
            if ($q > $max){
                $max = $q;
                $pref_language = $language[0];
            }
        }
        $pref_language = trim($pref_language);
    }

    if (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])){// in case there is no http_accept_language create it by hand
        $pref_language = "de";  
    }
$_SESSION['pref_lang'] = $pref_language;  //registers the session in case there is no one
$pref_language = $_SESSION['pref_lang'];   //is needed to select the right footer

 }else{   //in case that there is already a session with the saved language

    if  (isset($_REQUEST["fr"])  ) {  //if a new language will be choosen overwrite the old session with the new entry and header to correct path to show the page in the desired language
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = 'fr';
        header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/'.$pref_language.'/'.$basename);
    }elseif (isset($_REQUEST["en"])  ) {
        $_SESSION['pref_lang'] = 'en';
        header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/'.$pref_language.'/'.$basename);
    }

    $pref_language = $_SESSION['pref_lang'];  //needed in case that the path is correct to select the right footer version
 }
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '<form method="post">      
            <input type="submit" id="en" name="en" value="en"/><div>englisch</div>
        </form>
        <form method="post">  
            <input type="submit" id="fr" name="fr" value="fr"><div>französisch</div>
        </form>';
?>
```

when

```
print_r ($_SESSION);
```

on an other blank page, the session will be the default one "de"?

if there is someone who could help me out, i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Comment: See the article here that teaches the design pattern for this sort of thing.  I'll try to show you a code sample in a moment.  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_8910-A-Polyglot-Web-Site-in-PHP.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version and see if it makes sense to you.  Be sure to delete your session cookies before the first test ;-)

```
<?php // RAY_temp_bonny.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

$form = <<<ENDFORM
<form method="post">
Choose Language:
<br/><input type="submit" name="pref_lang" value="de" /><div>german</div>
<br/><input type="submit" name="pref_lang" value="en" /><div>englisch</div>
<br/><input type="submit" name="pref_lang" value="fr" /><div>französisch</div>
</form>
ENDFORM;

// IF SOMETHING IS POSTED TO REQUEST THE LANGUAGE
if (!empty($_POST['pref_lang']))
{
    $_SESSION['pref_lang']  = $_POST['pref_lang'];
    $_SESSION['pref_basis'] = 'POST REQUEST VARS';
}
// IF NOTHING IS POSTED TO REQUEST THE LANGUAGE
else
{
    // IF THE SESSION PREFERENCE IS NOT ALREADY SET
    if (empty($_SESSION['pref_lang']))
    {
        // IF NO PREFERENCE IN THE REQUEST VARS, CHOOSE GERMAN
        if (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]))
        {
            $_SESSION['pref_lang']  = "de";
            $_SESSION['pref_basis'] = 'DEFAULT CHOICE';
        }
        // IF THERE IS A CHOICE IN THE ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['pref_lang']  = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2));
            $_SESSION['pref_basis'] = 'HTTP_ACCEPT';
        }
    }
    // IF THE SESSION PREFERENCE WAS PREVIOUSLY SET
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['pref_basis'] = 'PREVIOUS SETTING';
    }
}

echo " CHOSEN LANGUAGE IS: " . $_SESSION['pref_lang'];
echo " AND THE REASON IS: "  . $_SESSION['pref_basis'];
echo $form;
```

This will use a default value (either "de" or the HTTP_ACCEPT) if no specific language request has been made.  If the client has requested the language, it will preserve the requested language in the session.

Comment: okay, the pref_language still does not change. when reloading the page, it will be set back to default. just the pref_basis will be displayed the correct way.

Comment: The script is on my server here.  The behavior is that the chosen language remains the preference through repeated access. Please test it and watch the screen. Then navigate away and come back to the page to check the language.  http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_bonny.php

Comment: this is strange. on your server it works as it should do. did you changed something at the on code? thanks.

Comment: at the "on code"?  Are you testing the most recently posted code example?

Comment: sorry, typo. okay, i recognized the following: i copied the whole code and called it on its directory. there it works, but only on this page. the problem is that i insert this external php by include_once at the top of my index page. now the thing is that when unsetting the session, and calling the index page it will error like i told before. even when calling a blank page that just print_r the session the session has not changed at all? that is so strange.

Comment: okay, now i got it!!! the problem is the default settings of the server and the host address. www. will be deleted. so that i tried that on two different pages. OMG this must be a joke. thank you so much for helping me. i wish you a merry christmas.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you, too.  The default setting of the PHP session cookie does not take into account the subdomain.  So www.domain.com does not share a session with domain.com.  You can get around this by setting the session cookie yourself.